# Regex for extracting URL parts?

Tags: javascript, regex, url

I have a JavaScript script I need help modifying... 
I'd like to have URL parts extracted and set as classes of the html element.

```
var loc = window.location.pathname.match(REGEX_CODE_GOES_HERE);
// document.documentElement is the html element, this adds the class
if(loc) document.documentElement.className += " " + loc[1].toLowerCase();
```

The hard part is the regex; this is how it should work:

Example URL:

```
http://www.somesite.com/Lists/Pages/ViewPage.aspx?ID=12
```

Should return (as classes of html element, of course):

```
lists pages viewpage aspx id 12
```

Feel free to edit the code around in anyway you seem fit...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

something like

`var split = window.location.pathname.split(/\/|\?|&|=|\./g);`

or if you want all in one string:

```
var classes = window.location.pathname.toLowerCase().replace(/\/|\?|&|=|\./g," ")
```

might do what you want

Comment: I'd suggest using `\W` instead of specific chars if javascript supports this.

Comment: but there might be non-word characters in parameters that you do not want to be delimiters

Answer (score 2):

```
var matches = window.location.pathname.replace(/http:\/\/[^\/]+\//,'').match(/[\w\-\.!~\*\'"(),]+/g);
```

The regex complies with RFC 1738.

Converting each array element to lowercase should then be a trivial matter.

Comment: This only will not work. You can join this solution, to the previous, like that: var loc = window.location.pathname.replace(/http:\/\/[^\/]+\//,'').split(/\/|\?|&|=|\./g);

Comment: @Alexandre: I suggest you test it before making a comment that it "will not work"

Comment: Sorry @stillstanding, but I've tested on firebug, and it worked! I've only replaced 'window.location.pathname' with the given example URL. But your solution, after the last edition is working as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
var match = url.match(/^(?:([^:/?#]+):)?(?:\/\/([^/?#]*))?([^?#]*)(?:\?([^#]*))?(?:#(.*))?/);
var protocol = match[1],
    domain   = match[2],
    path     = match[3],
    query    = match[4],
    fragment = match[5];
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of the URL API

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL_API

```js
var url = new URL("http://www.somesite.com/Lists/Pages/ViewPage.aspx?ID=12");

var pathnames = url.pathname.split('/');
// pathnames = ["", "Lists", "Pages", "ViewPage.aspx"]

// removes the first empty string
pathnames.shift();
// pathnames = [Lists", "Pages", "ViewPage.aspx"]

// lower case all entries in the array
pathnames = pathnames.map(i=>i.toLowerCase())
// pathnames = ["lists", "pages", "viewpage.aspx"]

// grab the last item since its the filename
var filename = pathnames.pop();
// filename = "viewpage.aspx"
// pathnames = ["lists", "pages"]

// create a css classes string that consists of the pathnames and the filename
var cssClasses = pathnames.concat(filename.split('.')).join(' ');

// now we need to grab the query params
var queryParams = new URLSearchParams(url.search);

for (const [key, value] of queryParams.entries()) {
    cssClasses += ` ${key} ${value}`;
}

console.log('cssClasses =', cssClasses);
```